# C fread omits 0x0D

Tags: c, fread

My code reads a file into an unsigned char* array. The file is in fact a text file with "normal" line endings 0x0D, 0x0A, and is 64 bytes long.

```
FILE * inputFile = fopen(sInfile.c_str(), "r+");
unsigned char * readArray = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*readSize); //readSize=64
int bytes_read = fread(readArray, sizeof(unsigned char), readSize, inputFile);
```

but bytes_read is 59 and when I examine the readArray, it does not have any \r (0x0D) but the file does.
Why is fread skipping all these values? Is there a setting that controls this?

Comment: Windows... Use rb+ instead of r+  ... can't find a good duplicate

Comment: @deviantfan - Consider posting that as an answer with an explanation.  It'll be more useful to future visitors.

Comment: If it is any consolation, it is not just `fread()` that skips the CR (carriage return, `'\r'`) characters; so too will `getc()` and all the other input functions.  Also note that 0x1A (aka control-Z) may cause problems, marking EOF.  If you open the file in binary mode, they will not be issues.  Also, the output functions in the libary will replace `'\n'` (NL) by `"\r\n"` (CRLF).  On Unix, using the `b` flag is a no-op; all files are always in binary mode and the CRLF to NL end-of-line mapping does not occur.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is what a line break is exactly, in different OS.
On Linux, it's a byte with (ascii) value 10, also written as `\n`.

On Windows, originating from MSDOS, it is *two* bytes in the file: 13 10 (`\r\n`), but only in the file:
If read by a program, `\r\n` becomes only `\n` in your variable,
and if something with `\n` is written out to the file, it gets converted to `\r\n` again.

That's what you're observing here, it converts the different line breaks. To turn this behaviour off, a additional "b" (as in binary) is necessary in the fopen mode, eg. `r+b` instead of `r+`.

On Linux, there is no special behaviour like that, \n stays \n everywhere.
It's no error to use the "b" too, but it won't be different with or without.

Btw., old Mac OS versions had another variant, only \r, but this is history.

Comment: And the behavior of `fread` is defined in terms of calls to `fgetc`. It does (or doesn't do) the same kind of processing on text input as `fgetc` or `fscanf`, translating each line ending to a single `'\n'` in text mode, or reading raw bytes in binary mode.